# Unity C# - Face a diagonal direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have a gameobject face in a diagonal direction on x and y (don't worry about the z).

This code already works for facing to the east:

```
Vector3 newEuler = citizen.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles;
newEuler.x = 0;
newEuler.y = 90;
transform.eulerAngles = newEuler;
```

And this works for facing north:

```
Vector3 newEuler = citizen.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles;
newEuler.x = 270;
newEuler.y = 0;
transform.eulerAngles = newEuler;
```

But this doesn't make it face northeast:

```
Vector3 newEuler = citizen.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles;
newEuler.x = 270;
newEuler.y = 90;
transform.eulerAngles = newEuler;
```

What values could I use?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What direction is exactly diagonal???

Comment: Like. The first code I posted makes him face 90 degrees, or to the east. I want him to face northeast, or 45 degrees, but just putting y = 45 doesn't seem to work

Comment: When I make myEuler's y 45, it faces east as if I had put 90

Comment: Had yuo tested with localEulerAngles???

Comment: No. Honestly I don't know Euler angles work. Could you help me

Comment: Please, first try insead of .eulerAngles, .localEulerAngles, in the two cases `citizen.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles` and `transform.eulerAngles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use `Quaternion.LookRotation`

```
//Vector3 south = Vector3.down;
//Vector3 north = Vector3.up;
//Vector3 east = Vector3.right;
//Vector3 southWest = Vector3.down + Vector3.left;
//.. you get the idea

Vector3 northEast = Vector3.up + Vector3.right;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(northEast);
transform.rotation = rotation;
```

This is assuming your camera is facing in the positive z direction.